# Select query in date data type is DATE with where condition

Tags: sql, database-design

I use table `function`

```
id    date
1     2014-02-26
2     2014-05-26
3     2014-02-20
4     2014-01-26
```

Now how to select records date in without year like `01-26` format `mm-dd`

I want result like

```
id  date
4   2014-01-26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate function MONTH() and DAY() of column

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 01 AND DAY(`date`) = 26
```